# `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- geometry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

When trying to run rails 2.3.11 server, I keep running into this: `` `gem_original_require': no such file to load — geometry ``.

Let me know if you have any questions about what I’m using or the like; I’m rather new to Rails so I’m not really sure what info to provide you all with.

[Here’s a trace of `rake gems:install —trace`](http://pastebin.com/ewJhJhNR)

Comment: For starters, can we get some information on the gems being loaded and how you are using them?

Answer (score 0):

My bet isn't that you've specified the `geometry` gem in your `Gemfile` and another gem (or perhaps you) is trying to load it. I don't know the exact name of this gem so I can't tell you exactly the line to put in your Gemfile, but it looks like this:

```
gem 'ruby-geometry', '0.2.8'
```